# Invalid URI: Invalid port specified when url has more than one colon

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, uri

I am using dnsdynamic.org to point to my personal website hosted at my home. My home ip will be frequently changing once a month. dnsdynamic.org provide a web method call to update ip.

```
https://username:password@www.dnsdynamic.org/api/?hostname=techno.ns360.info&myip=127.0.0.1
```

When I call this through browser it works perfect. When I try to call this through c# code it throws the following exception.

```
Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.
    at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
    at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String requestUriString)
```

Since there is a colon in the url it looks like system.uri try to parse my password as integer.

I tried adding a port after .org

```
https://username:password@www.dnsdynamic.org:443
```

no luck with this.

could someone please point me how to resolve this error.

I tried with don't escape and escape option while creating uri, still not working.

```
var ri = new Uri("https://username:password@www.dnsdynamic.org/api/?hostname=techno.ns360.info&myip=127.0.0.1",true);
```

EDIT:
It looks like the username is causing the problem. My username is my email address. And my email address end with *.com. So uri is trying to parse my password.

Still no solution found to overcome this issue. I can't change my username since dnsdyanmic.org use the email address as username.

Comment: I just copied your code into a new Visual Studio project and it works as is.

Comment: Works for me too, in both 3.5 and 4.5; what version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me this. The problem seems to be my username having *.com. My username is my email address. Please try the same code with a email address instead of username.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using an `HttpWebRequest` to make the reqeust, you shouldn't include the credentials in the URI (as you can tell, it's invalid).

You should instead add the credentials to the `HttpWebRequest` and let it handle passing them through:

```
// Only broke this up for readability
var uri = new Uri("https://www.dnsdynamic.org/api/?hostname=techno.ns360.info" + 
                  "&myip=127.0.0.1", true);
var cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add(uri, "Basic", new NetworkCredential("username", "password"));

var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Credentials = cache;
```